# Abstração da classe Connection PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, solid

Pessoal tenho a seguinte classe para conexão com banco de dados...

```
namespace App\Database;

class Conn
{
    public static function getDb()
    {
        return new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dkse','root','root');
    }
}
```

É uma classe bem simples e está funcionando no momento.. porem futuramente no meu projeto provavelmente vou precisar utilizar outro banco de dados por exemplo MSSQL, gostaria de saber como implementar uma interface.. para eu simplesmente implementar as classes de conexão do meu projeto seguindo os princípios de SOLID.. obrigado!

Comment: Desconheço como funciona o MSSQL, mas considerando que todas as dependências estejam instaladas, não seria apenas alterar o parâmetro na instância do PDO?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma classe Connections que seria sua interface com o banco de dados a frente de sua classe CONN, dentro dela no construtor definir qual tipo de banco de dados irá utilizar. Após instanciar a classe Connections de acordo com o banco de dados que for acessar basta criar os métodos em ambas as classes com o mesmo nome, deve utilizar o mesmo nome nos métodos em ambas as classes que fazem tratamento de queries. Isso vai evitar desvios de fluxo no seu código.

Ou criar uma classe abstract e herdar em sua classe CONN e dentro da classe abstract desenvolver o método que define qual tipo de banco de dados ira utilizar fazendo CONN acessar os métodos também para tratamento das querys em ambos os tipos de bancos.

Sugestão para efeito de manutenção futura, a primeira maneira é mais eficiente.

Possuo alguns sistemas que funcionam suportando versões antigas do mesmo dessa forma se ainda houver dúvidas eu posso postar um exemplo em php de funcionamento.

Vou montar um exemplo simples :

```
Arquivo Classe Modelo Connections 

class Connections{

   public function __construct($TDatabase){   
         if(strcasecmp($TDatabase,"MYSQL") == 0){
             $CONN_MSSQL  = new MSSQL();
         }else{
             $CONN_MYSQL  = new MYSQL();
         }
    }
}

MSSQL ARQUIVO CONSTANTES mssql.var.php
define('HOST','ip de acesso ao BD');
define('Porta','porta que seu banco de dados trabalha');
define('user','usuario de acesso ao banco');
define('senha','senha de acesso ao banco');


Arquivo Classe Modelo MSSQL

include mssql.var.php

class MSSQL{

     public function __construct(){
        // estabelece conexão com o banco MSSQL, utilize as constantes 
        //definidas no arquivo var     
     }

     public function GetAllUsuarios(){
        /* metodo executa querie no banco de dados MSSQL pegando todos os 
           clientes cadastrados*/
     }
}


MYSQL ARQUIVO CONSTANTES mysql.var.php
define('HOST','ip de acesso ao BD');
define('Porta','porta que seu banco de dados trabalha');
define('user','usuario de acesso ao banco');
define('senha','senha de acesso ao banco');



Arquivo Classe Modelo MYSQL

include mysql.var.php
class MYSQL{

     public function __construct(){
        // estabelece conexão com o banco Mysql, utilize as constantes 
        //definidas no arquivo var     
     }

     public function GetAllUsuarios(){
        /* metodo executa querie no banco de dados MYSQL pegando todos os 
           clientes cadastrados*/
     }
}
```

Pronto construído uma estrutura bem simples de funcionamento apenas para aumentar o entendimento para acessar o banco você deve chamar de qualquer interface de seu sistema dessa forma :

```
$Connections   = new Connections('MYSQL');
$listaUsuarios = $Connections->GetAllUsuarios();
print_r($listaUsuarios);
```

Repare que assim estou lendo os dados do MYSQL porque informei no construtor da classe Connections o banco que eu queria trabalhar.

Essa forma mantém a independência dos dados, ou seja separa o sistema do tipo de banco de dados que está utilizando. Como também reduz o acoplamento no sistema.

Segue conexão no padrão singleton 
[image: Conexão singleton]

Fico feliz se ajudar 
Abraços Salomão.  =P

Comment: Legal agradeço, porem estou usando MVC, e a conexão eu injeto em um container.. para utilizar nos models.. e a classe precisa ser estática =X

Comment: Ok nesse caso você pode tirar a conexão de dentro da classe MSSQL e MYSQL e criar uma nova camada atrás usando a conexão com static em padrão singleton

Comment: Seguindo dica do Everton editei a resposta para deixar mais organizado!